# множественное определение в c++

Tags: c++, объявление, extern

Есть такой файл заголовок(header).

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H
enum { SPRITE, PANEL };
struct global {
        int width;
        int height;
        int programs[ 2 ];
        int color;
        char *root;
};
struct global global;
#endif
extern struct global global;
```

Такой код без проблем компилируется в си, но в с++ возникают ошибки. Как тут справиться, если мне нужна логика сишной программы? Или как надо делать?

Вот ошибка

```
/tmp/ccCJF1ju.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `global'
/tmp/cckmT2vV.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccsDCDPj.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `global'
/tmp/cckmT2vV.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Comment: Укажите сообщение об ошибке и представьте минимальную готовую программу, которая воспроизводит проблему.

Comment: Указал, забыл об этом написать, что множественное определение.

Comment: Во-первых, вы не предоставили код. Заголовочный файл - это еще не код. Во-вторых, проблема одинакова и в С, и в С++. То, что это у вас компилировалось в С - не более чем странность вашего компилятора С.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по сообщениям об ошибке, ваш код страдает от проблемы множественного определения вызванного определением объекта *с внешним связыванием* в заголовочном файле.

- Во-первых, требования, предъявляемые к таким определениям, одинаковы в С и в С++. Ваш код одинаково ошибочен и в С, и в С++. То, что он у вас "компилировался" в режиме С является не более чем особенностью/странностью/глюком вашего компилятора.
- Во-вторых, у вас в коде наблюдаются попытки решить эту проблему при помощи т.наз. "include guards" (`#ifndef` и т.д.). Include guards не имеют никакого отношения к этой проблеме и никак ее не решают.
- В-третьих, выбор правильного варианта может зависеть от дополнительных требований. Если вам не нужна кросс-компиляция вашего С++ заголовочного файла в С коде, то достаточно определить в заголовочном файле

  ```
  #ifndef GLOBAL_H
  #define GLOBAL_H

  struct global {
    ...
  };

  inline global global;

  #endif
  ```

  и все. (Использование одного и того же имени для класса и для объекта - не ошибка, но и не самая лучшая идея).

  Если же вам нужна кросс-компиляция с С кодом, то тогда вам придется идти по "классическому" пути: в заголовочном файле лишь объявлять

  ```
  extern struct global global;
  ```

  а в одном файле реализации определить

  ```
  struct global global;
  ```

  Однако при этом надо еще не забыть согласовать спецификации линковки (!) при помощи `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 0):

У вас объект структуры

```
struct global global;
```

определяется во всех модулях, куда включен данный заголовок. Поэтому и выдается сообщение о множественном определении.

Вам следует вместо этого определения включить объявление объекта структуры в заголовок

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
    //...
    extern struct global global:
#endif
```

А в каком-нибудь модуле его определить

```
struct global global;
```